# Android Camera process the frame data in previewCallback cause increasingly native memory

Tags: android, android-camera, android-profiler

I use `camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);` to reuse the buffer to avoid out of memory. My code in previewCallback like

`checkFace(data, camera);
camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);`

In method checkFace just convert data to bitmap then using FaceDetector to check faces. And I have try to use `camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);`after converting data, but the native memory show in Android Studio profiler like [image]

after my app running about 10 minutes, the "Native" increase from 10MB to 250MB.

When my app running about 4 hours, it will crash and Logcat print :

> E/IMemory (17967): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x11515160), size=462848, fd=70 (Out of memory)

I think maybe because of the  "Native" memory increasingly

CODE:

```
camera1.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(previewCallback1);
camera1.addCallbackBuffer(buffer1);
camera1.startPreview();
```

...

```
private Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback1 = (data, camera) -> {
    checkFace(data, camera);
    camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
};

//convert data to bitmap then check face from the bitmap
private void checkFace(byte[] data, Camera camera){
    ... 
    ...run on new Thread...
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapUtil.ByteToBitmap(data, camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize());
    ...
    FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), numberOfFace);
    ...then get the result of face detection
}

//convert frame data to bitmap
public static Bitmap ByteToBitmap(byte[] data, Camera.Size previewSize) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    Bitmap bitmapOut = null;
    try {
        int w = previewSize.width;
        int h = previewSize.height;
        YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, w, h, null);
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, w, h), 60, baos);
        byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();
        bitmapOut = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
        if (null == bitmapOut) {
            return bitmapOut;
        }
        jdata = null;
        yuvimage = null;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        bitmapOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOut, 0, 0, w, h, matrix, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            if (baos != null) {
                baos.flush();
                baos.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    return bitmapOut;
}
```

So, what should I do to resolve it ???

Comment: Could you please include the code too so we would know where to start...

Comment: @BennyHawk I had post my code